Why potential energy is not considered in the internal energy of diatomic molecules?
In thermodynamics, I am taught that there are 5 degrees of freedom in diatomic molecules since there are 3 for translational and 2 for rotational. I interpret degrees of freedom as "ways you can move the diatomic molecule", since you can translate the molecule in $x, y, z$, and rotate the molecule about 2 different axes but not a third one going through both atoms as the atoms are like point masses.
Therefore, by the equipartition theorem, the internal energy of the diatomic gas is $\frac{5}{2}nRT$.
But that's just the kinetic energy; why don't we include potential energy here? Internal energy is the system's total energy, consisting of kinetic and potential energy. I have seen some people describe the diatomic molecules as "rigid", so the separation of the atoms is not a degree of freedom. Still, a diatomic molecule should have a non-zero potential energy due to the covalent bond.

Note that potential energy is defined on a relative scale, and so we are free to chose the state which we call the zero potential energy state. Since the diatomic molecules are considered rigid, their potential energy stays constant in time, and this is where we chose to define the zero. This changes, however, at high tempepratures when the vibrational degrees of freedom come into play. In this regime, the molecules may no longer be considered rigid, and an additional contribution from the vibrational degrees of freedom will be seen in the expression for your total heat capacity. For a diatomic gas, you see one vibrational dof - along the molecular axis - which means your total dofs are now 6 (3 translational + 2 rotational + 1 vibrational). The new heat capacity will then accordingly be $3nRT$.

You're right - there is an additional degree of freedom from the potential energy of the bond! In fact, there is also another kinetic degree of freedom from the relative motion of atoms as they stretch and compress the bond (think of it like a spring, which has one kinetic and one potential degree of freedom). That means the total number of degrees of freedom is 7: 6 kinetic, and 1 potential. So why is the internal energy $\frac{5}{2}nRT$ and not $\frac{7}{2}nRT$?
The reasoning ultimately comes down to quantum mechanics. The equipartition theorem treats these degrees of freedom classically, where any given degree of freedom can have any amount of energy. But quantum mechanics tells us that the energy levels are quantized, and there is some minimum energy gap between the ground state and the first excited state.
If the temperature is much larger than this excitation energy, then the classical approximation works and the degree of freedom will contribute a $\frac{1}{2}nRT$ to the internal energy in accordance with the equipartition theorem. If the temperature is instead much smaller, then there isn't enough energy to even reach the first excited state and so the degree of freedom will contribute approximately nothing to the internal energy. This is sometimes referred to as the degree of freedom being "frozen out". (In the borderline case, the contribution will be something in between $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}nRT$, the exact value being a little more complicated to calculate.)
It turns out that at typical temperatures, the excitation energy for the translational and rotational modes is small enough that they can be treated classically, but the vibrational modes have much higher excitation energies so they get frozen out. Thus, assuming that the molecules are rigid is a valid approximation. At high enough temperatures, the vibrational modes will start to come into play and the internal energy will in fact be $\frac{7}{2}nRT$ instead.
For example, the CCCBDB gives the fundamental vibrational frequency of diatomic oxygen as $1556\,\mathrm{cm}^{-1}$, which corresponds to a temperature of $1966\,^\circ\mathrm{C}$.

There is intramolecular potential energy and intermolecular potential energy. The first applies to the chemical and nuclear bonds of the molecule/atom. The second applies to the potential energy associated with intermolecular forces.
If we are not considering chemical or nuclear reactions, then only the potential energy associated with the intermolecular forces of the diatomic molecule applies to the changes in internal potential energy of the system.
Hope this helps.

How is the translational and rotational velocity of the molecule an "intermolecular force"? Because isn't that what we're talking about when we say that a diatomic molecule has 5 DOFs and thus $\frac{5}{2}nRT$ internal energy?

@R.M. Where did I say the translational and rotational velocity of the molecule is an intermolecular force? My reference to intermolecular forces is to the internal molecular potential energy.

The question is about "5 degrees of freedom in diatomic molecules" and how "by the equipartition theorem, the internal energy of the diatomic gas is $\frac{5}{2}nRT$" but there's confusion about why that really should be the case because "a diatomic molecule should have a non-zero potential energy due to the covalent bond." -- So interpreting your answer in that context, the covalent bond doesn't count because it's not intermolecular, but the translation and rotation does ... because they are intermolecular? Or what exactly are you trying to say here?

@R.M. my answer pertains only to the CHANGE  in internal potential energy not involving chemical reactions.  Translational and rotational energy is kinetic energy. For that the chemical potential energy of the diatomic bond is irrelevant. Why don’t you post an answer of your own .

@R.M. did you downvote my answer?
